# Subversion on Ubuntu - incremental dump changed revision number

Tags: svn, ubuntu, tortoisesvn, svnserve, svndump

Last week I took a dump of my subversion server. This week I mistakenly continued to commit on my old repository. Now I started to take an incremental dump from revision no 6713 to latest one.

```
svnadmin dump --incremental -r 6713:6720 /path/to/repository > rev6713.svn_dump
```

When I load it to new repository, I realised that I've already had the revision 6713 on my new repository. Therefore it automatically increased revision number one more when it loaded. Now whenever I try to update on my local computer by TortoiseSVN, it displays the comment of one revision earlier.
Example:

```
Revision 6719 no comment
Revision 6720 yes comment
```

It displays me on TortoiseSVN with Revision no: 6720 'no comment'.  So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Might be worth just doing a fresh check-out of the tree.

Comment: I did a fresh check-out, didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decide to take a clean dump of subversion server. But this error occured even with new dump. After a long search, I found that the error was because of cache of tortoiseSVN, Therefore I cleaned the cache of tortoiseSVN:

```
=> Right click on Folder - TortoiseSVN - Settings - Saved Data - Clear
```

Now, it works fine.